# what does -1 mean in waitpid(-1,WNOHANG)

Tags: perl

I know `waitpid(pid,WNOHANG)` is used to Non blocking wait for a child process to finish and once child process is finished it returns pid of the child itself. But what does -1 in place of child pid? AND what would be its returned value.

Comment: Why is this tagged `perl`?

Comment: What effort did you make in trying to find this out yourself?

Comment: For your reference: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html

Comment: @alk : because i found it in perl code and later found it's defined in c

Comment: can any 1 explain why -ve voted, i can see answers are useful to others as well (more than 1 upvotes)

Comment: The Perl reference here: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking for, @Bharat. Why you got downvoted or what?

Comment: @cad yes why i got downvotes :)

Comment: The question receives downvotes most probably because it does not show any evidence you took the minimal efforts yourself to make it a "good" question, that is at least reading the documentation.

Comment: @alk : i gone through the doc of perl(which doesn't have answer), i don't much about c so i skipped , anyways ur help is appreciated.

Comment: The first hit on gxxgle: https://www.google.com/search?q=perl+waitpid (you perhaps want to train your gxxgle foo ;-))

Comment: @alk go and read http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html and tell me where is anything mentioned about -1 IN ARGUMENT.

Comment: Right in the middle: "*If you say

        `use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
        #...
        do {
            $kid = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG);
        } while $kid > 0;`

then you can do a non-blocking wait for all pending zombie processes.*"!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99127/discussion-between-bharat-and-alk).

Comment: The perl docs are lacking there. If you want to suggest a more useful wording, you can submit it using the `perlbug` tool.

Answer (score 5):

From [`man waitpid`:](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid)

> The value of pid can be:
>
> [...]
>
> -1
>
> meaning wait for any child process.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Return Value
>
> [...]
>
> `waitpid()`: on success, returns the process ID of the child whose state
>   has changed; if `WNOHANG` was specified and one or more child(ren)
>   specified by `pid` exist, but have not yet changed state, then `0` is
>   returned. On error, `-1` is returned.

(Code formatters added.)

Comment: The perl specific page is [`perldoc waitpid`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html) - says basically the same thing, but frames it a little more perlishly.

Comment: @BradLarson When re-editing a post of mine, could you **please** explain why you did it? "RTFM" is absolutely appropriate here, IMO. I don't know exactly how such stuff's handled here (and since you're a moderator you're probably right) but I regard an answer as *my* content (unless it's community wiki), so, if you dislike something, downvote it and write a comment. Editing is for stuff like formatting. And I regard the "RTFM" as a crucial part of my answer (seriously). :-)

Comment: @cad - In general, telling someone to RTFM is considered to be rude and doesn't really add anything to your answer. You've already pointed them to the appropriate reference above, so this edit doesn't impact the content of your answer, it just modifies the tone.

Answer (score 1):

From the linux manual :

> The pid parameter specifies the set of child processes for which to
>   wait. If pid is -1, the call waits for any child process.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`waitpid` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html):

> The value of pid can be:
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> -1     meaning wait for any child process.